# Compiler error using restrict qualifier on certain C++ compilers

Tags: c++, restrict

I have a function that has pointers of `double` as argument that are qualified as `restrict`. Note that the Intel compiler uses `restrict`, but we replace the qualifier by `__restrict__` in case of GCC.

```
void Stats::calc_flux_2nd(double* restrict data,
                          double* restrict datamean,
                          double* restrict w)
{
    // ...

    // Set a pointer to the field that contains w,
    // either interpolated or the original
    double* restrict calcw = w;

    // ...
```

This code compiles without any problems using GCC or Clang, but the IBM BlueGene compiler gives the following error:

```
(W) Incorrect assignment of a restrict qualified pointer.
Only outer-to-inner scope assignments between restrict pointers are 
allowed.  This may result in incorrect program behavior.
```

I do not understand how to interpret this error as I do not change the signature of the variable, nor do I know whether I am introducing undefined behavior or whether the IBM BlueGene compiler is wrong.

Comment: restrict is only a C keyword, as far as I can tell it is not a  C++ keyword.

Comment: @Chiel If you remove the assignment to the variable `w`, does the warning disappear? It sounds like restrict is not working exactly similar compared to the GCC/clang versions.

Comment: @Leandros If I introduce a declaration without assignment, it does not trigger errors. Apparently IBM does not like to assign a `double* restrict` to an existing `double* restrict`, even though in my view there is no risk. I can imagine that assigning a non-restrict pointer to a restricted variable can invoke undefined behavior, but this puzzles me...

Comment: @RichardCritten. I know, but as many compilers support it, plus I need it to reach high performance, I would still like to use it without introducing undefined behavior.

Comment: As a comment, I tried this on today's latest version of the `xlc` compiler for ppc64le on linux (v16.1.1.3) and it compiles just fine. Perhaps they've fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your construct is not supported by IBM's XL C/C++ compiler, it's also stated in their [documentation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2LWA_12.1.0/com.ibm.xlcpp121.bg.doc/language_ref/restrict_type_qualifier.html?lang=en). You cannot assign restricted pointers to each other. You can fix this, by creating a new block scope and a new set of pointers.

```
{
  int * restrict  x;
  int * restrict  y;
  x = y; /* undefined */
  {
     int * restrict  x1 = x; /* okay */
     int * restrict  y1 = y; /* okay */
     x = y1;  /* undefined */
  }
}
```

Comment: I know that it is not an official keyword in C++, but all relevant compilers support it, and it without it, it is nearly impossible to write code that properly vectorizes. Nonetheless, IBM is warning me for undefined behavior and I want to be sure to not introduce that into our code.

Comment: As far as I know, IBM's compiler are somewhat GNU C compatible, try using `__restrict__` or `__restrict`, instead of the official C keyword.

Comment: I am using the proper restrict keyword for the proper compiler, that is not where the error is.

Comment: Oeh, nice edit to your answer. This makes a lot clear. Can you explain why this solution helps the compiler?

Comment: @Chiel I can only speculate.